# Is there a way to nest an enum within a data class in Kotlin?

Tags: syntax, enums, kotlin

Is there a way to nest an enum within a data class in Kotlin?

```
data class D(val a:Any) {
    enum class E {F,G}
    ...
}
```

Or to declare it inline within a function?

```
fun foo() {
    enum class E {F,G}
    doSomething()
}
```

I can't find documentation on the rules for where enums are allowed to be declared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no kotlin specification for the syntax at present. if you want to find the specification  you can see [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9), because Kotlin is based on Java, so some specifications also appropriate in Kotlin.

> A nested enum type is implicitly **static**. It is permitted for the declaration of a nested enum type to redundantly specify the static modifier.
>
> This implies that it is impossible to declare an enum type in the body of an **inner** class (§8.1.3), because an inner class cannot have **static** members except for **constant variables**.
>
> and, all [local class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)es are **inner** classes.

**So** the `enum` class can be declared anywhere except the `local` function scope and `inner` classes.

If you don't sure where can define a type you can try to prompt the scope in turn: `local` > `class` > `top`, then the kotlin compiler will give you the correct compiler error message to you. for example:

**IF** you define a `const val` in the local function, the compiler report the error as below:

```
fun local() {
    const val foo="bar"
    // ^--- the modifier `const` is not applicable to `local variable`  
}
```

**IF** you define a `const val` in the common class/interface, the compiler will report the error as below:

```
interface Foo {
  const val foo = "bar"
  //^--- `const val` only allowed on top-level or objects.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What do you mean by "prompt the scope in turn"?  Is that a feature of IntelliJ?

Comment: @Julian just as put your code in each scope in turn. and I have gave an example of `const val`.

Comment: Actually there *is* a syntax spec on the official site: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html It's rather incomplete though. There are edge cases that the grammar shown on that page allows but is rejected by compiler. I can't remember a concret case ATM, though. Feel free to add this info to your anwser.

Comment: @glee8e No. the gammar is broad and it is not precised. just like as java gammer.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can nest the enum in a data class, but not in a function:

```
data class Outer(val a: InnerEnum) {
    enum class InnerEnum { A, B }
}

fun foo() {
    val o = Outer(Outer.InnerEnum.A)
    println(o) // --> Outer(a=A)
}
```