# Is it possible to nest an enum contains class's properties within an open class?

Tags: kotlin

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911809/is-there-a-way-to-nest-an-enum-within-a-data-class-in-kotlin), it doesn't address my specific case.

Here's my minimal case:

```kotlin
open class BaseCase() {
    lateinit var txtNode: UiObject

    enum class TextType(val field: UiObject) {
        PlainText(txtNode)
    }
}
```

But there's error:

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `txtNode` is an instance variable. Different `BaseCase` instances could have different values. So the enum cannot know which one of them to take.

Let's for simplicity say `txtNode` is a `String` instead of an `UiObject`

Then how would the following code work?

```
val a = BaseCase()
a.txtNode = "test"
val b = BaseCase()
b.txtNode = "test2"
val c = BaseCase.TextType.PlainText
```

would `c` have "test" or "test2" as field? It simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

that's because enum class are final static classes ---> you cannot access non static variables.
for testing -> if you move your variable to companion object the code will work